# why i can get root after running system("/bin/sh") in c file?

Tags: shell, permissions, root, c

I am currently logged in as `seed` and after running test.c, on my Ubuntu system, I get `root` permission. I am just wondering why `system("/bin/sh")` can make a such change?

Firstly, I `su root` and compile test.c in `#`, and also `chmod 4755 test`. When I exit #, run file and get `root`

```
[04/03/2018 05:27] seed@ubuntu:~/Desktop/assignment$ id
uid=1000(seed) gid=1000(seed) groups=1000(seed),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(s 
ambashare),130(wireshark),1001(vboxsf)
[04/03/2018 05:27] seed@ubuntu:~/Desktop/assignment$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){


system("/bin/sh");
printf("successful!");
return 0;


}
[04/03/2018 05:27] seed@ubuntu:~/Desktop/assignment$ ./test
# whoami
root
# id 
uid=1000(seed) gid=1000(seed) euid=0(root) groups=0(root),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare),130(wireshark),1000(seed),1001(vboxsf)
```

----update-----

```
[04/03/2018 06:03] seed@ubuntu:~/Desktop/assignment$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 13  2013 /bin/sh -> dash
[04/03/2018 06:04] seed@ubuntu:~/Desktop/assignment$ ls -l test
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 7198 Apr  3 05:56 test


[04/03/2018 06:14] seed@ubuntu:~/Desktop/assignment$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-37-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 10 17:51:56 UTC 
2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[04/03/2018 06:14] seed@ubuntu:~/Desktop/assignment$ ./test
# uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-37-generic #58~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 10 17:51:56 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Maybe you have set SUID bit on `/bin/sh`. Please show `ls -l /bin/sh`.

Comment: Or maybe you just have SUID on `./test`, you should also show us what `ls -l test` says.

Comment: This may be because you compiled as `root` and `chmod 4755`, so the SUID is set to the owner of the file, in this case is root

Answer (score 4):

First, you compile your program as root, so resulting binary is owned by root:

```
[04/03/2018 06:04] seed@ubuntu:~/Desktop/assignment$ ls -l test
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 7198 Apr  3 05:56 test
#            ^^^^
```

Second, by running `chmod 4755 test` you set [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit on `./test`:

```
[04/03/2018 06:04] seed@ubuntu:~/Desktop/assignment$ ls -l test
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 7198 Apr  3 05:56 test
#  ^
```

That means, your binary is run as its file owner (=root), not as user that started it. That's why `/bin/sh` spawned by it is also run by root.

Comment: That's correct. The inquiry in here is why ending the program, the effective user stays as root?

Comment: @tachomi the program hasn't yet ended; it's still running the subshell.